# Bash script: MySQL query over SSH not queried as I want

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

I'm trying to run the following over SSH via a BASH script:

```
for register in ${@:3}; do
     ssh host "mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -D DATABASE -e 'CALL DATABASE.domain('$2', '$register');'"
done
```

Where $2 is e.g "google.com" and $register is another domain which will loop depending how many registered domain I have, e.g "mydomain.com".

When I run the script the query cuts off ".com" only for $2 but inputs the right text for $register. So it looks like this if I use "google.com" and "mydomain.com":

```
for register in ${@:3}; do
     ssh host "mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -D DATABASE -e 'CALL DATABASE.domain('google', 'mydomain.com');'"
done
```

When I echo out the text I get the full FQDN for $2 but not when I try to run it via mysql.

Comment: Adding `set -vx` in your script will help you debug. There is no apparent reason, why this is not working.

Comment: As ~@anishsane says this should work - indeed it does for me.  Can you post the entire script, and the command you are using to call it together with the output when you've included `set -x` please?

Comment: Well, I tried just running the following:
ssh host "mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -D DATABASE -e 'CALL DATABASE.domain('google.com', 'mydomain.se');'".

And I get the following error:
ERROR 1109 (42S02) at line 1: Unknown table 'google' in field list.
(Where google.com is available in the field list but not "google")
Is there anything wrong with the apostrophes?